# Iterate over IDictionary with implicit DictionaryEntry

Tags: c#, idictionary

Consider this code:

```
var variables = System.Environment.GetEnvironmentVariables();
foreach (DictionaryEntry vari in variables)
{
    Console.WriteLine(vari.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(vari.Value);
}
```

It works fine. Since `variables` is `IDictionary`, it consists of `DictionaryEntry`, with `object Key` and `object Value`.

Why cannot I type `foreach(var vari in variables)`? It gives me

```
error CS1061: 'object' does not contain a definition for 'Key/Value'...
```

It seems strange and I cannot find a reason for this behaviour. `DictionaryEntry` is a `struct`, but I can iterate over a `List<DictionaryEntry>` all right. Of course I understand that `IDictionary` is not generic, but the [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.collections.idictionary.aspx) says it contains `DictionaryEntries`, so it should be possible to use `var`...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Why cannot I type foreach(var vari in variables)?

Well you can - but then `vari` is implicitly of type `object`.

You happen to know that each entry within the iterator is a `DictionaryEntry`, but the compiler doesn't. As far as it's aware, the iteration element type of `IDictionary` it just `object`. Even though `IDictionary.GetEnumerator` returns an [`IDictionaryEnumerator`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.idictionaryenumerator.aspx), that still has a `Current` property with a type of `object`, not `DictionaryEntry`.

Annoyingly, this *could* have been done better. If `IDictionaryEnumerator` had been implemented using explicit interface implementation for `IEnumerator.Current`, and provided a new `Current` property of type `DictionaryEntry`, then this would have worked *and* been more efficient as it would have avoided boxing.

Section 8.8.4 of the C# spec provides the rules the C# compiler uses to determine the element type of a collection.

EDIT: For those who wanted to see how `IDictionaryEnumerator` *could* have been declared, here's a short but complete example. Note how this doesn't use generics anywhere, but *does* use `var` in `Main`, still with a variable implicitly typed as `DictionaryEntry`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

interface IJonDictionary : IEnumerable
{
    new IJonDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator();
}

interface IJonDictionaryEnumerator : IEnumerator
{
    new DictionaryEntry Current { get; }
}

class JonDictionary : IJonDictionary
{
    private readonly IDictionary dictionary = new Hashtable();

    public object this[object key]
    {
        get { return dictionary[key]; } 
        set { dictionary[key] = value; }
    }

    public void Add(object key, object value)
    {
        dictionary.Add(key, value);
    }

    public IJonDictionaryEnumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new JonEnumerator(dictionary.GetEnumerator());
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    private class JonEnumerator : IJonDictionaryEnumerator
    {
        private readonly IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator;

        internal JonEnumerator(IDictionaryEnumerator enumerator)
        {
            this.enumerator = enumerator;
        }

        public DictionaryEntry Current
        {
            get { return enumerator.Entry; }
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current { get { return Current; } }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            return enumerator.MoveNext();
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            enumerator.Reset();
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dictionary = new JonDictionary { 
            { "x", "foo" },
            { "y", "bar" }
        };

        foreach (var entry in dictionary)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}", entry.Key, entry.Value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is interesting. How could it have been done better? `IEnumerator` calls `Current` from `IEnumerator`, so how could we provide a new implementation? I've just made an explicit implementation of `IEnumerator` with another `Current` property returning my specified class, but it still does not work the way I intended. Could you please provide some sketch solution?

Comment: @PiotrZierhoffer: The compiler will generate a call to `Current` itself - and it will call whatever `Current` has been provided. I would *expect* foreach to just do the right thing here. However, that does mean that the compiler needs to know the exact type being iterated over - you can't use `IEnumerable foo = ...; foreach (var x in foo)`.

Comment: Jon, there is one thing I do not understand. Quote: "If IDictionaryEnumerator had been implemented using explicit interface implementation for IEnumerator.Current, and provided a new Current property of type DictionaryEntry" But how one could do that? I mean that when implementing interface (or overriding method) you *can't* change the type of a result, i.e. the return type is not covariant. You perhaps had something different on mind?

Comment: @konrad.kruczynski: You can do exactly as I said - implement `IEnumerator.Current` with explicit interface implementation, and declare a separate "normal" `Current` property. The C# compiler would then pick it up in the foreach loop. I'll give a full example of that when I get a chance.

Comment: @JonSkeet so if I understand you correctly, it is a bad design of the IDictionaryEmulator's implementer? I'll have to play with it a bit. Would it be possible to break foreach just by leaving the explicit interface implementation and NOT providing any other overload? I'll need to take a look into documentation...

Comment: @JonSkeet: either I did something wrong or the method you've described does not work. The separate Current property weren't used, foreach loop utilized the explicit interface implementation... The behaviour is also consistent, when taking Piotr's comment into account.

Comment: @konrad.kruczynski: It does work - see my edit with a complete example.

Comment: @PiotrZierhoffer: It's bad design of the `IDictionaryEnumerator` interface, IMO. There's no reason why `Current` can't be redeclared with a type of `DictionaryEntry` - just as it's redeclared as `T` within `IEnumerable<T>`. See my edit for a complete example.

Comment: @JonSkeet: now I see, the point is the `new` keywoard on the derived interface, I've tried to do it with a simple fully explicit IEnumerator implementation and an additional Current field. Thanks!

Comment: @konrad.kruczynski: That could work as well, depending on the type that you *declared* `GetEnumerator` to return.

Comment: @JonSkeet: indeed, I finally read the spec instead of trying to guess :) The rule is not so straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't *explicitly* provide the type for `vari`, it's considered `object` since `variables` is `IEnumerable`, not `IEnumerable<DictionaryEntry>`

```
//As you can imagine this won't work:
foreach (DictionaryEntry vari in variables) {
    object v2 = vari;
    Console.WriteLine(v2.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(v2.Value); 
}

//This works!:
foreach (var vari in variables) {
    DictionaryEntry v2 = (DictionaryEntry) vari;
    Console.WriteLine(v2.Key);
    Console.WriteLine(v2.Value); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

foreach loop contain explicit cast. So you'll get something along inside foreach loop:

`vari = (DictionaryEntry)e.Current;`

In case of `object` you'll get cast to object, thus making calls to `Key` and `Value` non-compiling.

From ***C# Spec***  **8.8.4 The foreach statement**:

```
foreach (V v in x) 
  embedded-statement
```

is translated into:

```
{
    E e = ((C)(x)).GetEnumerator();
    try {
        while (e.MoveNext()) {
            V v = (V)(T)e.Current; //explicit cast
            embedded-statement
        }
    }
    finally {
        … // Dispose e
    }
}
```

consider Eric's article on this topic [Why does a foreach loop silently insert an "explicit" conversion?](http://ericlippert.com/2013/07/22/why-does-a-foreach-loop-silently-insert-an-explicit-conversion/)